# SOAP Service call - Getting error Illegal Request format for element

Tags: c#, service, wsdl

We are integrating a service from a third party. They have recently upgraded their service, and now with the new wsdl, I keep getting "Illegal Request format for Element".

From my investigations the problem seems to be with the xmlns that is added on the main element. If I use SOAPUI and remove the xmlns from the main element, it works, however visual studio adds it automatically in accordance with whats defined in the wsdl.

What is interesting is that with their previous wsdl, the service works with the xmlns included, it is only with the new wsdl that it throws an exception.

In terms of the wsdl, all I know is that they used JD 12 and manually created the wsdl, however upon comparing it, it looks similar to the old one with the name in the xmlns being the only difference.

This is the request visual studio creates:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <extractacccategElement xmlns="http://gna160ws/Management.wsdl/types/">
            <xSecurity>
                <timekey></timekey>
                <authkey></authkey>
                <publkey></publkey>
                <version>1.x</version>
            </xSecurity>
            <xRequest1>
                <supplierno></supplierno>
            </xRequest1>
        </extractacccategElement>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

With the "xmlns="http://gna160ws/Management.wsdl/types/"" causing the problem.

Response:

```xml
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <srvc:extractacccategElementResponse xmlns="http://gna160ws/Management" xmlns:srvc="http://gna160ws/Management">
         <srvc:result>
            <response1Out>
               <origin>gna160.extractacccategElement</origin>
               <invsql>1200</invsql>
               <message>Illegal Request format for extractacccategElement.</message>
            </response1Out>
         </srvc:result>
      </srvc:extractacccategElementResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

When submitting the same request, but without the xmlns, I get a valid response. Example:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <extractacccategElement>
            <xSecurity>
                <timekey></timekey>
                <authkey></authkey>
                <publkey></publkey>
                <version>1.x</version>
            </xSecurity>
            <xRequest1>
                <supplierno></supplierno>
            </xRequest1>
        </extractacccategElement>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Response:

```xml
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Body>
    <ns0:extractacccategElementResponse xmlns="http://gna160ws/Management" xmlns:srvc="http://gna160ws/Management">
       <ns0:result>
          <ns0:acccategOut>
                <ns0:invsql>0</ns0:invsql>
                <ns0:message>Success</ns0:message>
                <ns0:origin>gna160pkg.ExtractAccCateg</ns0:origin>
                <ns0:stage>1</ns0:stage>
                <ns0:acccategcode>A</ns0:acccategcode>
                <ns0:acccategname>AAA</ns0:acccategname>
          </ns0:acccategOut>
       </ns0:result>
    </ns0:extractacccategElementResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Additionally, if I add a qualifer after the xmlns then it also works??
Example:

xmlns:hello="http://gna160ws/Management.wsdl/types/"

I have been working collaboratively with the developer on their side and we have not yet been able to identify the problem.

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your service reference with the new WSDL?

Alternatively you can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507942/adding-a-custom-namespace-to-soap-envelop-in-wcf) from Rick Strahl: override the following function to add a custom namespace.

```
protected override void OnWriteStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
{
        writer.WriteStartElement("soapenv", "Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "oas", null, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "v2", null, "http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/ship/V2");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "v1", null, "http://www.royalmailgroup.com/integration/core/V1");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsd", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");            
}
```

[Link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Apr/02/Custom-Message-Formatting-in-WCF-to-add-all-Namespaces-to-the-SOAP-Envelope) to his complete article

Comment: Yes I did update the service reference. Thank you for suggesting the above answer, however I have multiple different services, would the above not impact all requests to the different services?

Comment: Additionally, I dont know if the above will work, as I need to either remove the xmlns from the element completely, or add a qualifier after the xmlns like :name